# Fill dropdownbox by query and use content as link parameter (Pentaho)

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am very new to Pentaho (and Pentaho CDE), but got sent to a customer that has a huge, undocumented pentaho/JavaScript codebase which does various things. Most important is the feature that before calling a report, you can pass parameters by selecting entries from dropdown boxes. The person that wrote the current JS didn't seem very organized, so I doubt that copying the "structure" will produce good code. My main problem is that I don't think Pentaho made it so difficult to implement the scenario and this codebase just seems screwed and as if the framework was circumvented.

When searching the net, maybe I didnt know the right buzzwords, but I just found how to alter Pentaho reports once you have them open. My usecase is to just pass a few parameters in the URL.

[image]

So how would one build the following usecase in Pentaho:

Show a lot of links to xanalyzer- and prpt-reports that come from a database. You can click those names so that you can enter a filter. This filter is supposed to be a dropdown box whose values are filled at startup by a SQL query. When selecting such an entry, opening the report will add the selected option to the URL (there is code that does this concatenation).

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

A CDE dashboard looks like it would do the job. You have components for Analyzer or PRPT reports. Should be fairly simple to setup.

There are assorted video tutorials on getting started with CDE on youtube.
You also have a couple of paid tutorials at Kagi (and I think IvyIS also provide one).

Comment: can you provide a link so a free tutorial doing that? btw the Pentaho version is 5 and we do use CDE already

Comment: The first 6 here (except for #2) should give you a good starting point (and some links to relevant bloggers): https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=CDE+tutorial&search_sort=video_date_uploaded